# python django - exclude class from makemigrations

Tags: python, django

Let`s say I have a class:

```
class A(models.Model, GrandparentClassSharedByAllClasses):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=False, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('test')
        verbose_name_plural = _('tests')
```

can I somehow exclude it from makemigration/migrations?

Why would I want that? -> Class A is one of manny classes of which all others save the objects in the db. Class A should bring the same functionality like the other classes, so it can be used in the same pipeline, but not be stored in the db.

Comment: I am not fully aware what you are asking, but perhaps `managed=False` Model Meta option would help. Django will create no db tables for this model. It is usually for db views.

Comment: @EzonZhao thank you for your answer! I will have a look at it, but it looks promising. If that solves it,

Comment: Flag abstract=True also stops creation of database tables. But it is used for an abstract base class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be AbstractModel so fields from it are added to migration of child models like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=False, null=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.value

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('test')
    verbose_name_plural = _('tests')
    abstract = True


class B(A):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=123)
```

Then your B model will be stored in db with fields:

```
id
value
name
```

There is example in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). Class A won't be migrated to database. But if you have legacy database (tables exists in database and you dont want to change them) you can create your models manualy with meta `menaged=False` like @Ezon Zaho wrote or you can run:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Which will return model list of existing tables in database. You need to remember to add this database to your settings.py as describe here [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)